# Positioning & Sizing Android DialogFragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

We have the following scenario:

The user can select a button in an Activity which results in a DialogFragment being shown.

This DialogFragment is positioned in such a way that a view (lets call it anchoredView) within the DialogFragment is positioned directly over the button which was depressed. This works fine.

The user can interact within the DialogFragment but certain actions that the user undertakes can result in another Fragment being loaded in a FrameLayout in the DialogFragment. This results in a resizing of the DialogFragment to occur, and as a result this can result with the anchoredView no longer being aligned over the initial button.

To address this mis-alignment we look at what we should set the (x,y) of the DialogFragment to be, which does result in anchoredView being positioned correctly again, directly over the original button.

But... we end up with a visual aspect which aren't ideal, namely when the DialogFragment is going to grow in size we briefly see the Fragment get bigger and then jump back when the (x,y) is set.

It would appear that an additional layout occurs as a result of the settings of the (x,y,) but this doesn't occur when the size changes, so you get this visual jump occurring. Checking whether currently in a layout when in process of setting (x,y) shows we are currently in a layout so, AFAIK this change will occur on the next layout.

Is there anyway in which we can get this so that the move and the re-size (due to specification of new Fragment in a FrameLayout) occur within the same layout to hopefully loose the visual 'jump'.

We've tried adjusting the (x,y) in the SizeChanged,OnMeasure & OnLayout of the root layout in our DialogFragment without success.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override onResume() method in your DialogFragment like following:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    final Window dialogWindow = getDialog().getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialogWindow.getAttributes();
    lp.x = 100;        // set your X position here
    lp.y = 200;        // set your Y position here
    lp.width = 300;    // set your Width here
    lp.height = 400;   // set your Height here
    dialogWindow.setAttributes(lp);

    super.onResume();
}
```